# Send txt file through URL with c# & PHP?

Tags: c#, php

So basically I've been trying to figure a way to send a text file i receive from a users computer, (Im doing this to allow users to upload certain text files to my website, kinda like storage(i know it sounds kinda stupid)) then once its retrieved i will send the data (from the text file) to my website using the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userDocPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string Path_ = Path.Combine(userDocPath, "RevTech", "Source", "Custom.txt");
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string txt = File.ReadAllText(Path_);
            wc.DownloadString("https://example.com/k/gettext.php?source="+txt);
        }
```

Once that is called i have a page hosted on my server that uses PHP to `$_GET['source']` then i use this and use

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $_GET['source']);
fclose($myfile);
```

Then when i check to see if the text file was successfully added to my server it doesn't correctly? Hopefully you all understand my question, if you did do any of you possibly have a solution to it? By the way sorry for my bad English

Comment: It's better to use a POST method rather than GET.

Comment: Where does it fail? When you post the .txt to the server? When you attempt to retrieve it back? Or when the server (your php code) is looking for it?

Comment: @haxard it fails when creating the text file on my server.

Comment: @RevTech what error are you getting?

Comment: @haxard It says something within the lines of "The url is too long", im guessing its because i use GET to get the contents of the text file which is something around 5,000 lines of code?

Comment: @RevTech Are you actually trying to store the contents of the .txt in the URL? Just to be clear, the URL is that string of characters that looks like "http://myServer.com". That....that isn't going to work. It has a max length of 2083 characters.